# Asp.Net Mvc 5 image not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have same images in **Content** and **Views** folders. I am trying to display images as below:

```
<img src="~/Content/Images/download.png" alt="Content folder" />
<br />
<br />
<img src="~/Views/Home/download.png" alt="Views folder" />
<br />
```

The image in **Content** folder displays successfully but the one in Views folder doesn't display and gives below error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

[image]

But actually, the resource is there. Here are my folders:

[image]

Could you please tell me which point I am doing wrong? I am using MVC 5 with razor engine and Visual Studio 2015 community edition.

Comment: why you are adding images in Views directory? you should'nt

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, but why mvc could not found the file?

Comment: try this src="@Url.Content("~/Views/Home/download.png")"

Comment: @M.Azad, did not worked

Comment: Because views folder is not for that purpose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you changed the default configuration, folder `Views` contains file `Web.config` that has settings for restricting access to files in this folder:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" 
           type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

So you can either remove this handler (which is not recommended for security purposes), or move your static files to some other folder, e.g. `Content`.

Answer (score 3):

Its because of the inbuilt security of ASP MVC to protect your views being accessed directly. Check removing '`BlockViewHandler`' handler entry from `~/Views/web.config`

My advice is to move image to '`Content`' folder and keep '`Views`' folder clean.

Answer (score 3):

Any MVC Version **not allow** to load **other resource except html** from Views folder.
Because when you call a URL it waiting for **text/html content type** and because of that image inside main Views folder not able to render in page.

for better information please check file **header request and response** in browser (development tool/F12) network tab.

**Response of image from Views:**

[image]

**Response of image from content folder:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In .net core 3 you will also need this below line in startup.cs

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\images")),
                RequestPath = "/wwwroot/images"
            });
```

Comment: It works, acctually, you should just change `@"wwwroot\images"` by `@"wwwroot/images"`

Answer (score -1):

```html
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Views/Home/download.png")" alt="Views folder" />
```