# I am using CaptchaMvc.MVC5 package but instead of captcha it is showing cross image in login page only

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, captcha

I have tried to create a POC application with CaptchaMvc and its working within controller action method. But when I am trying to add this behavior to my application login page its displaying a cross image always. Tried changes in Route.config and Web.config changes as suggested in stack overflow. But those didn't help much. Links below didn't help.

[Asp.Net Mvc 5 image not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556570/asp-net-mvc-5-image-not-displaying)
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/captcha-not-show-normally

Answer (score 0):

Tried the below stack overflow information and it didn't help much.
[Asp.Net Mvc 5 image not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556570/asp-net-mvc-5-image-not-displaying)
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/captcha-not-show-normally